# Custom web server & self-signed certificate

Tags: python, ssl, https, self-signed

First of all let me to say my knowledge of ssl and criptography protocols is very limited. Please be patient if I say something blatantly wrong :-) . Feel free to correct me!

I'm building a custom web server to be deployed inside an isolated local network; this is how I run my service (Python code):

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile='mykey.crt', keyfile='mykey.key')
... client connects to https port 443 ...
ssl_sock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True)
```

This is how I generated mykey.crt and mykey.key files:

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out mykey.orig.key 2048
$ openssl rsa -in mykey.orig.key -out mykey.key
$ openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out mykey.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in mykey.csr -signkey mykey.key -out mykey.crt
```

So far so good, my webserver works very well. But I have go past the "not secure" warning that Firefox rightfully shove in my face.

I'd like to install my self-signed certificate in the few clients that are going access my web server in order to permanently avoid the warning.

I followed every single certificate installation guide I was able to find but I absolutely cannot get Firefox (and Chrome) accept my certificate. And I get no error message whatsoever from the browsers.
I think I'm missing something in the certificate generation commands.

Somebody could help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check what the warning in the browser actually says (maybe look at the advanced information). My guess is that the content of the certificate does not match the URL you use to access your server.

Comment: I really cannot find any place where Firefox or Chrome show the reason of the refusal of my certificate. Also I cannot find my certificate listed among the other already present, so I think it's a certificate problem even before my clients try to connect to my web server. I'll check the URL, anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

self-signed certificate can uses only for tests. You have to get the certificate from an 'Accredited certification authority'

2) check please : self-signed certificate need to has next data:
URL, address,
name,
email

3) you should use a certificate signed by a CA

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but using a certificated signed by a CA is not an option because the devices that will access this website aren't connected to the Internet so they will not be able to verify the certificate. Moreover, I cannot ask my client to buy a certificate and keep track of the renewal.